# Two almost similar Android projects having same project structure in eclipse not installing in my phone

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

I am trying to make a game using Libgdx. I am new to Android and LibGDX.
I made a simple game skeleton that contains the Player with abilities to move and jump and an enemy.
I did all using Scene2D and without using that. The more I started coding, the code seemed to be mesy.
I wanted to separate my project into 3 projects into eclipse.

I made two different workspcaes at different locations.
I used different names in .project file. Even I changed the name of application in the string.xml of resources
from where AndroidManifest.xml takes their name.I even changed the launch icons for them.
Both projects with some different are running very well.

But when I am deploying them on my Samsung Cell, I am able to install one application at a time.

I noticed a strange behaviour .. I am unable to solve this. First it took me alot of time to run the same 
application in the diffrent workspace that was running well in my previous one.After I resolved that somehow,
this started. Please suggest on how both the projects are considered the same by Eclipse.

Though the structure of the project is same. But all the dependencies are assets are entirely separated.
How else to do distinguish them for eclipse.

Comment: Post the manifest file of both apps

Comment: Can you post the .project file for both projects (it will be in the project root folder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't install two apps with the same package name:

```
package="com.jungle.main"
```

Change one of them and you'll be fine.
See also: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package

Comment: In eclipse right click your project -> Android tools -> Rename application package